# How to change the default module docstring in Spyder?

Tags: module, settings, spyder, docstring

How to change the default template for new modules in Spyder IDE?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on %(date)s

@author: X
"""
```

Answer (score 43):

**Preferences > Editor > Advanced settings > Edit template for new modules**

[image: changing default docstring for modules in Spyder]